# Zoom far in on an image with Xlib

Tags: c, zooming, xlib

I have an ximage which I want to zoom in on, and display. I'm currently taking the naive approach:

```
allocate bigger image
use nearest-neighbor interpolation to fill it in.
put the whole image on a pixmap.
```

Which works, but slowly, and crawls once I approach bigger zoom levels, like 800%. The gimp, however, can zoom in to 3200% and still feel snappy. What's the approach taken here? Should I only fill one screen at a time? But then what about scrolling: wouldn't performing interpolation, and an XPutImage, and an XCopyArea on each expose kill performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not expert in Xlib, but in my opinion a good approach would be to draw only the zoomed part, instead of computing the interpolation of the entire image.

For scrolling, if you are looking for performances, you may copy the part of the old zoom which is still visible in the new position, and compute the interpolation of the "discovered" pixels. For example, when scrolling down, you may copy the bottom of the previous image and paste it higher, and then compute/draw the new visible stuff at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern X11 applications don't use Xlib directly much, if at all. My guess would be that Gimp is rendering the zoomed image into a buffer itself and drawing that to the window, rather than working with the image in an XImage.

Comment: Yes, but Gimp leverages gdk, which uses Xlib or xcb. Either way, without shared memory pixmaps (another thing I was considering) you're performing X11 PutImage requests.

Comment: At some level, yes. But Gimp is almost certainly not storing the entire canvas in a single XImage and making XLib / X11 do the scaling -- it's much more likely to be rendering a separate image whenever the canvas is zoomed/scrolled, so that the images it sends around are no larger than the onscreen window.

Comment: But, do they perform the interpolation onto a buffer, which they put on the window, or do they perform interpolation on a per-expose basis?